# Caret disappears after CKEditor is hidden in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, ckeditor

Problem: If CKEditor instance is hidden, when it is exposed again, the caret is invisible.  Firefox only.

We noticed the cursor disappearing problem when switching tabs in our app.  After returning to the CKEditor tab, the cursor is gone.  Typing still inserts text.

Narrowed it down to: If you set the style of the element containing the CKEditor instance to `display:none`, and then `display:block`, the problem reproduces.

Comment: Well, `display: visible` does not exists. Do you mean `visibility: visible` or `display: block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a viable solution for posterity, better than re-creating the entire editor: set the `<body>` element of the editor to `contenteditable="false"` and then back to `true`, the cursor reappears.

From: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=21787

Comment: I meant display:visible to say make the element visible.  In truth I'm doing dojo.style(element, 'display','') to return the element to return it to default display.  Changed the post to make it more clear - thanks.

Comment: This works for me: $('#cke_contents_editorBody > iframe').contents().find('body').attr('contenteditable',false);
$('#cke_contents_editorBody > iframe').contents().find('body').attr('contenteditable',true);             Where "editorBody" is the id-attribute of my original textarea.

Comment: Thanks for another suggestion.  We ended up switching to Dojo's editor.